# Superblock errors after 2 new installs

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, ssd, hardware, ext4

I have a 2 yr old Samsung SSD 850 Pro 128GB drive. With a fresh format, I installed Xenial on it a couple of months ago.

Once in a while I would get I/O errors with bad super block. So, I copied over my home dir with `cp -a` to a back up. Then I reformatted the drive and re-installed Xenial. Then I copied over my home dir files to my new home.

About a week after the second install, I got I/O errors again with a bad superblock.

I ran smart tools on my SSD and everything looked good. I also ran memtest to make sure my memory was good(for like 12 hours), and everything passed.

Any ideas what is causing this file system corruption? Could my SSD be dieing even though it is only 2 years old and is a reputable Samsung brand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I fixed the issue. The issue was with the latest version of Chrome. What led me to suspect was I would see `print_req_error` which I believe would only come from Chrome, as nothing else would use a printer.

I may be completely wrong on this. However, I switched to chromium and I have not had the ATA errors so far.